Identify this Short Film where a couple’s relationship plays out on an Answering Machine
I'm looking for a poignant short film, where the story of a couple's entire relationship arc is told through answering machine messages (with cassette tapes, flashing red lights, “Beep”, etc.)
I think it showed on HBO or Showtime back in the late 80’s or early 90’s.  It might have been an episode in Showtime's “30-minute Movie" series, or maybe just a short "filler" film between other feature-length movies.
No actual people appeared in the film – just the husband’s and wife’s voices on tapes, with the changing home environment and decorations (and new, more "modern" answering machines) as seasons changed and the years passed.
The story begins with (paraphrasing), "Hey, it's Steve. We met the other night and, uh, you gave me your number. Thought, ya know, maybe you might like to get a drink sometime?", and ends with, "The lawyer says you might be able to get the kids on weekends and every other holiday" – and every high and low in-between.
After extensive searching of the internet, IMDb, Google, and YouTube with no success, I was hoping the Stack Exchange community might have some insights.  Does anyone else recall this film?  Or know where we can view it again?
I only saw it once, but over 25 years later I can still recall the film’s emotions: the couple’s early joys of each other, evolving into a bittersweet marriage, and ultimately succumbing to a heartbreaking separation.  That's how powerful it was.  It was a perfect execution of a brilliant concept, and I know there must be others who are searching for this short film, too.
